# Calling ConnectionString from another class in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I've added a connection string in web.config.
I made a class where a string calls it -

```
namespace WebApplication1.Classes
{
    public class Connections
    {
        public string DBConn = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HomeDB"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Now from my default.aspx.cs page I want to call this DBConn so I can use it in that page.

```
 namespace WebApplication1
 {
     public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(Classes.Connections.DBConn);
         }
     }
 }
```

The `Classes.Connections.DBConn` is not working. This is the error I get.

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'WebApplication1.Classes.Connections.DBConn'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PaulG - I was wondering the same thing.  The question is clear and has all the details to answer it.

Comment: I dont know either. Was there a similar question already, cause I looked and didnt find one

Comment: From the available options of what makes a downvote, the most reasonable is "no research effort". Type "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" into google and guess whether the answer is on the first link available or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field isn't `static`. In order to call it like this:

```
Classes.Connections.DBConn // Using the class Connections, 
                           // not an instance of the class Connections
```

You have to declare the field like this:

```
public static string DBConn = "etc";
```

For such a class, it might behoove you to declare the whole class as `static` in fact. For more information, check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To fix, pretty much just follow the error message by making it static instead:

```
public static string DBConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HomeDB"].ConnectionString;
```

Since this expression `Classes.Connections.DBConn` is a static reference (you don't have an instance of `Connectinos`) you need to make it static if you want to access it in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public static string DBConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HomeDB"].ConnectionString;  }
```

The reason it's not visible is because you have to make it `static`

Comment: Sounds like something else went wrong (maybe a DB error), you should use Try Catch and try to zero in on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Classes
{
 public static class Connections
 {
   public static string DBConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HomeDB"].ConnectionString;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your variable isnt static, you need to instantiate the class Connections like this:

```
Connections x = new Connections();
```

Then you will be able to access it via

```
x.DBConn
```

Other solution would be to make your variable static

```
public static string DBConn=...
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the connection string as your classes are currently written, do the following:

```
using WebApplication1.Classes;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Connections().DBConn);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a widely accepted practice to create a `static` class for application wide settings - similar to other examples shown.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a variable without an instance, it must be declared static.  Read more on the static keyword [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If there's no reason for your class to be instantiated either, you should mark both the class and the variable as static:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Classes 
{ 
 public static class Connections 
 { 
   public static string DBConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HomeDB"].ConnectionString; 
 } 
}
```

The static on the DBConn variable allows it to be accessed from the class itself (i.e., without an instance).  The static on the Connections class prevents the class from being instantiated, since there is no reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things:

1) instance your class

```
Connections c = new Connections();
```

then use `c.DbConn`

2) make the method static

```
  namespace WebApplication1.Classes
  {
    public class Connections
    {
      public static string DBConn = 
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HomeDB"].ConnectionString;
    }
  }
```